# Chrome DevTool panel docked to right issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use dev tools panel docked to the right to test various screen resolutions/widths. After right click to inspect element I have to resize the panel again as it resizes to last width before inspecting element. It's utterly annoying.
I could not find any chrome bugs in their bugtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search more carefully :) This sounds like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225705, which was fixed around a week ago (and the fix should be in the Canary now).