# Prevent Chrome Dev Tools panel from snapping back to its original position

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There is a very annoying issue with the Chrome Dev Tools in Chrome version 26 and a couple of versions back on Mac (tested on XP as well, no issues there).

The panel snaps back to some seemingly arbitrary (sometimes its initial) position/size every time "Inspect Element" is used either with the context menu or the keyboard shortcut.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Move or scale the dev tools to the desired position/size
2. open/chose another tab
3. go back to the orignal tab
4. panel should stay the same in position and size
5. repeat steps, when a new position size is chosen

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225705, which was fixed around a week ago (and the fix should be in the Canary now).

A duplicate of [Chrome DevTool panel docked to right issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540329/chrome-devtool-panel-docked-to-right-issue/16559460).